# Select only day of week (Mo, Tue) and time using Bootstrap 3 DatePicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

After looking through this article [Bootstrap 3 DatePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/), I have a question to create multiple date and timepicker using these formats at below:

```
Monday:18:00
Friday: 14:30
```

Actually, I don't need to take a concrete date like `09.01.2016`. It is enough for me choosing the day of week and time, as I described above. Does Bootstrap provide this method?

Comment: You can break the date using a simple script. Assume you fetched the dd-mm-yyyy, you can then break it and get arrays from it

Comment: You can use a `<select>` to chose the day of the week and then a datetimepicker to select hour. You can initialize the picker with `format: "HH:mm"` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following format: `"dddd: HH:mm"`.

For example:

```
$('your-element').datetimepicker({
  format: "dddd: HH:mm"
});
```

Comment: This method is good, if I able to hide dates (not days of week) and add multiple choosing function

Comment: in this method i click to the date. I am looking for the way to click to the days of week and choose time.